# form.valid is not getting updated even though the form is valid in reactive forms angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have implemented reactive forms my form.valid is not getting updated even after filling the required fields. My form.valid is false even after filling all the required fields. But the form.value is getting update properly but same with both form.valid and form.invalid flags are not getting updated

UI looks like this

```
    <div class="form-feilds">
  <div class="form-content">
    <form [formGroup]="personalInfo" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div formArrayName="details" *ngFor="let field of personalInfo.controls.details['controls']; let index = index;" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
        <div class="row formgroup1" [formGroupName]="index" *ngIf=" tabIndex === index">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 first-form">
            <div class="row margin">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                <label class="pull-right">First Name*</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-5">
                <label class="pull-right">Full Middle Name*</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fullMiddleName">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2" style="margin-top: 9px;">
                <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="none">
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                <label class="pull-right">Last Name*</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                <label class="pull-right">Suffix</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="suffix">
                  <option>Ms.</option>
                  <option>Mrs.</option>
                  <option>Mr.</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                <label class="pull-right">Gender*</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="gender">
                  <option>Male</option>
                  <option>Female</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                <label class="pull-right">Maiden Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="maidenName">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                <label class="pull-right">Driver License #</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="licenseNumber">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                <label class="pull-right">Driver License State</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="licenseState">
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
                  <option>4</option>
                  <option>5</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                <label class="pull-right">Home Phone</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="homePhone">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
                <label class="pull-right">Mobile Phone*</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="mobile">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
                <label class="pull-right">SSN/SIN</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ssn">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6"><label class="pull-right">Date of Birth*</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input class="form-control text-color" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dob="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="dob">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary  text-color" (click)="dob.toggle()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line" *ngIf=" tabIndex === index"></div>
        <div [formGroupName]="index" *ngIf=" tabIndex === index">
          <div class="row formgroup2" formGroupName="currentAddress">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Current Address*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="currAddress">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Address Cont.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="addressCont">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">City*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="currCity">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">State*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="currState">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Zip/Postal Code*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="currCode">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Rent or Own ?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="currRent">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Landlord Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="landlordName">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Landlord Phone</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="landlordPhone">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Rent Amount</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="currAmount">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Rent Period</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"  formControlName="currPeriod">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Move in date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <div class="form-group calender-width">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control text-color" name="dp" formControlName="currMoveIn" ngbDatepicker #currMoveIn="ngbDatepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary text-color" (click)="currMoveIn.toggle()" type="button"><i
                            class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Move Out Date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <div class="form-group calender-width">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control text-color" name="dp" formControlName="currMoveOut" ngbDatepicker #currMoveOut="ngbDatepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary text-color" (click)="currMoveOut.toggle()" type="button"><i
                            class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-1 offset-sm-1 offset-xs-1 offset-lg-1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line" *ngIf=" tabIndex === index"></div>
        <div [formGroupName]="index" *ngIf=" tabIndex === index">
          <div class="row formgroup2" formGroupName="previousAddress">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Previous Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prevAddress">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Address Cont.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prevCont">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">City*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prevCity">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">State*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="prevState">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Zip/Postal Code*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prevCode">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Rent or Own ?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="prevRent">
                    <option>Rent</option>
                    <option>Own</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Landlord Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prevLandlordName">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Landlord Phone</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prevLandlordPhone">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Rent Amount</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="prevAmount">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Rent Period</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" formControlName="prevPeriod">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Move in date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <div class="form-group calender-width">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control text-color" name="dp" formControlName="prevMoveIn" ngbDatepicker #prevMoveIn="ngbDatepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary text-color" (click)="prevMoveIn.toggle()" type="button"><i
                            class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
                  <label class="pull-right">Move Out Date</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 col-lg-7">
                  <div class="form-group calender-width">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control text-color" name="dp" formControlName="prevMoveOut" ngbDatepicker #prevMoveOut="ngbDatepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary text-color" (click)="prevMoveOut.toggle()" type="button"><i
                            class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-1 offset-sm-1 offset-xs-1 offset-lg-1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, public shared: SharedServiceService) {
    this.shared.headingText = 'Personal Information';
    this.tabs.push({ title: 'Primary Applicant', id: this.tabsCount });
    this.personalInfo = this.fb.group({
      details: this.fb.array([this.createFormControls()])
    });
    this.shared.personalInfoFormDetails = this.personalInfo;}

    createFormControls() {
    const personalDetailsGroup = this.fb.group({
      firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      maidenName: new FormControl(''),
      homePhone: new FormControl(''),
      fullMiddleName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      none: new FormControl(''),
      licenseNumber: new FormControl(''),
      mobile: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      licenseState: new FormControl(''),
      ssn: new FormControl(''),
      suffix: new FormControl(''),
      gender: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      dob: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      currentAddress: new FormGroup({
        currAddress: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        landlordName: new FormControl(''),
        addressCont: new FormControl(''),
        landlordPhone: new FormControl(''),
        currCity: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        currAmount: new FormControl(''),
        currState: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        currPeriod: new FormControl(''),
        currCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        currMoveIn: new FormControl(''),
        currRent: new FormControl(''),
        currMoveOut: new FormControl('')
      }),
      previousAddress: new FormGroup({
        prevAddress: new FormControl(''),
        prevLandlordName: new FormControl(''),
        prevCont: new FormControl(''),
        prevLandlordPhone: new FormControl(''),
        prevCity: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        prevAmount: new FormControl(''),
        prevState: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        prevPeriod: new FormControl(''),
        prevCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        prevMoveIn: new FormControl(''),
        prevRent: new FormControl(''),
        prevMoveOut: new FormControl('')
      })
    });
    return personalDetailsGroup;
}
```

Comment: that is because `currentAddress` and `previousAddress` sub-controls have required fields and you need to supply those

Comment: Hi @JohnVelasquez I have updated the code in updated code there is currentAddress and previousAddress

Comment: why do you have multiple form tags? where it should be only one form tag

Comment: @JohnVelasquez there only form tag but multiple formgroupname becasue they are different formarray is used because in application the form is dynamic

Comment: then you should group also those controls which are not related to `currentAddress` and `previousAddress`, example: `info: new FormGroup({firstName, maidenName,homePhone ......})` so that it would not affect the validation of the other formgroups

Comment: then to validate it you can check via `this.personalInfo.get('info').valid`

Comment: So actually I am group like that only using details in the constructor and If this is the solution can elaborate please